# Why does this NOT cause crash? I am updating UI from other thread

Tags: dialog, thread-safety, android

This example is copied from a book on Android. As you can see from my question, I am new to Android and trying to understand. **This application should crash but it does not** (I am updating UI from another thread. Which is not allowed.It should cause a crash. It does not. Why?). My code is:

```
final ProgressDialog dialogue = ProgressDialog.show(this, "title", "message");

       new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                dialogue.dismiss();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



        }
    }).start();
```

This is done in `OnCreate` function. I am confused with line - `dialogue.dismiss();` Isn't that updating UI (dismissing dialogue) from another thread? Why does this app **not** cause segmentation fault?

Thanks.

Comment: probably the dismiss will simply leak the dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the [dismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()) method can be run safetly on any thread as described in the Android documentation.

> public void dismiss ()
>
> Since: API Level 1 Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen.
>   This method can be invoked safely from any thread. Note that you
>   should not override this method to do cleanup when the dialog is
>   dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().